# How to iteratively update a dictionary based on existing entries

Tags: python, dictionary

I came across the following issue when trying to iteratively update a dictionary in python:

```
import numpy as np

array_1 = [0.1, 0.2, 0.9]
array_2 = np.arange(0, 1, 0.1)

dict_A = {}
dict_A[0] = dict(zip([i for i in range(len(array_1))], [[[1 for i in range(len(array_2))] for j in range(len(array_1))] for k in range(len(array_1))]))

dict_B = {}
dict_B[0] = dict(zip([i for i in range(len(array_1))], [[1 for i in range(len(array_2))] for j in range(len(arra_2))]))

time = range(100)
for t in time:
    dict_A[t+1] = dict(dict_A[t])
    dict_B[t+1] = dict(dict_B[t])
    dict_A[t+1][np.random.choice()] = update_A()
    dict_B[t+1][np.random.choice()] = update_B()
```

When I run the actual version of this code, for each t > 0, dict_B gets an updated version of the dictionary saved at t-1, while for dict_A and all t, I save the same dictionary.

I'm sure I'm making an obvious mistake here. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Your code is difficult to follow. You have functions which we do not understand, `update_A` and `update_B`, which are likely critical for understanding your error, and you are initializing your dicts (which look like they should really just be lists, since the keys are integers) with overly verbose one-liners. (Tip, `[i for i in range(len(array_1))]` can just be `range(len(array_1))`. But I suspect your issue arises because `dict(dict_A[t])` Only makes a *shallow* copy of the dictionary values.

Comment: Indeed, I suspect your entire approach could improved by simply using multidimensional `numpy` arrays, and using `np.random`. But you really need to describe what you are trying to accomplish. I sense this is an XY-problem.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. The functions update_A() and update_B() simply modify parts of the dictionaries for t+1. But you were right, making a deep copy fixed the issue. As suggested, I'll switch to using numpy arrays. Seems like that is more intuitive for me. Thanks very much!